# how to use if statement in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, t-sql

I have query in SQL Server like this :

```
create trigger MyTrigger after updated on Customer
begin
declare @oldname nvarchar(50);

set @oldname = select d.CustomerName from deleted d
if(@oldname = 'John')
begin
      insert into tbl1(Name) values('John') -- An Insert For Example
end

end
```

`old.CustomerName` will give me `@oldname` value in SQLite;

I'm going to make something like above for SQLite; but I have a problem with **if** statement

how can i use **select case then** in SQLite for something like that? Or have I to use another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLite trigger syntax is *very* different to that of SQL Server. The simplest way is to use a `WHEN` clause to qualify the trigger. (Since this is a deletion trigger, we use `OLD` to “access the deleted row”.)

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger AFTER DELETE ON Customer
    WHEN OLD.CustomerName = 'John'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl1(Name) VALUES ( OLD.CustomerName );
END
```

However, that's very specific to this case! A more general approach is to use the magic power of relational algebra a bit more by pulling the thing to `INSERT` from a `SELECT` that produces an empty collection of rows to insert when the condition fails:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger AFTER DELETE ON Customer
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl1(Name)
        SELECT OLD.CustomerName AS Name
             WHERE OLD.CustomerName = 'John';
END
```

Comment: The other approach is to create a function that traps out to the host process and use custom code there to handle things. That's _very_ powerful as it can do virtually anything at all, but overkill for a problem like this.

Comment: Hi @Donal Fellows ; Thanks for the Solution it works fine; Can i have Two or more Condition in One Trigger? I mean and Insert for CustomerName = 'John' and an Update when CustomerFamily = '....' on tbl2 Table

Comment: @mohammadjannesary I think if they're triggering on different tables they need to be different triggers. If they're triggering on the same table, you can use a complex condition.